# Hover to custom shape. How to?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

How do I create a CSS triangle (for example) which will trigger the hover event only inside the borders of the triangle?

In practise, it will be location on the game and different objects on it, which should blur if we hover it.

Notice in this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/K2Xf2/) that the `span:hover` styles trigger when entering the element's rectangle bounds, not triangle.

Comment: Do you want in div to make triangle?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with elements and will probably have to use `canvas`.

Comment: there are some tags that could work, `map` and `area`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp you can also draw a triangle.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric try not to link to http://w3fools.com/, it makes the internet sad

Comment: can you show me, how i can do this with <canvas> ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to create the shape with [SVG polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG), and `:hover` will respect his "true" area.

**Note** this is a pure css + SVG solution only for custom shapes. And the custom shape it isn't created with pure css, but SVG...

A little bit of html

```
<svg width="120" height="120"
     viewPort="0 0 120 120" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="60,0 0,120 120,120"  id="shape"/>
</svg>
```

Very simple CSS!

```
#shape:hover{fill:red;}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfum7/).

**Browser support:**
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926285/svg-browser-support) send some light to the browser support. There's no accepted answers, but as far I can see there are very useful links and alternatives for browsers that do not support SVG.