# List of browsers and versions that supports SVG engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, orgchart

I am using `getorgchart` for the org chart and everything worked well until I tested in IE8. I got to know that `getorgchart` uses `SVG engine` for rendering. I tried using `svg2vml` tool to get my `getorgchart` to work but the issue is it won't support the `clickEvent` with 'svg2vml`. I would like to know if there is any work around to fix IE8 issue with clickEvent? If not would like to know the browsers and it's versions that supports svg, say like ...

```
IE9 +
FireFox?
Chrome version?
Safari?
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#SVG_on_the_web

Comment: Already answered in detail here:    [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14882471/1486486](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14882471/1486486)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any workaround for IE8 without using some other library such as http://raphaeljs.com/.  Here's info for browser support:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: Raphel js will render VML or SVG.. Good Suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the information ...! I wanted to try raphel but was not sure whether the clickEvent will work or not as svg2vml with clickEvent didn't work for me, any idea on that? like in orgChart when I click on one person it should call clickEvent of getorgchart

Comment: Haven't had to use it directly, but you can add click event handlers, so I'd think it would work:  http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click

Answer (score 0):

- Firefox 41 supported
- Chrome 46 supported
- safari 8 supported
- IE 9-11 supported