# Browser support for SVG attributes control in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use SVG graphics in order to display a AJAX loading spinner. This is animated using CSS animation, and it is changing SVG attributes in CSS.

For example, here is some parts of this code:

```
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124px;
  }
}
```

You can have a look at that here:
https://codepen.io/jczimm/pen/vEBpoL

But the problem is I'm afraid of browsers that may not support this feature (I mean controlling SVG attributes via CSS). I could not find any specific resource to find out which browser support such feature.

Can anyone provide any resources or more information about that?

**Edit**

I have to repeat my question, because of some misunderstandings:

**Which browsers support changing attributes of SVG elements using CSS?**

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: `I could not find any specific resource to find out which browser support such feature` This means that you didn't search before. There are exact duplicated posts in stackoverflow, and more than 488.000 results in google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.SVG Browser Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926285/svg-browser-support)

Comment: Hey guys, I'm not asking about support of SVG itself, but using CSS to change its attributes.

Comment: Apply CSS to SVG element is supported by this table http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg . For supporting animations is different, as @makshh said you can see compatibility http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil

Comment: IE does not support CSS animation of SVG, other browsers do. It does support the CSS attributes themselves so you could animate them with javascript. On the whole wouldn't it be easier if you just tried it yourself?

Comment: @RobertLongson It is not so easy to find out which versions of browsers support it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have latest versions of browsers, and most of them support it, now how can I know about previous versions?