# Using SVG for Vectors and its compatibility with the browsers

Tags: html, css, svg, vector, cross-browser

I'm designing a website, and I have some vectors (colored vectors for landscape). I always had a concern about using SVG due to the browsers compatibility.

As we are in 2020, Is SVG fully supported now with all of its details in all browsers (web, mobile) ? or still working only for the basic vectors those don't have much details ?

Should I trust it for a website that will be used widely whether via web/mobile ? or better to stick with JPG / PNG ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All browsers have excellent support for SVG. You should have no worries about using it.

However you may want to avoid relying on some of the new bleeding edge features of SVG 2.
SVG 2 has not been finalised yet, and browser support for some of the new features is mixed.

Answer (score 1):

As a resume of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926285/svg-browser-support), pretty much all the modern browsers support at least partially SVG. You should definitely use it for simple images, but it's not wide supported for animations for example.

Note that some small display issues can happen, even with images. More information about it on [this page.](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/test-svg-format-browser-engines/)

Comment: I think your answer paints an overly pessimist picture of SVG support.  The first page you link to is old and out of date.  It is also incorrect that animation is not widely supported.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I modified my answer. Some browsers (mobile browsers for the majority) still don't support some svg, but you are right the link was probably outdated so i deleted it.